# How to fix "error: expected ']' [UIScreenmainScreen].applicationFrame];"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

```
       UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame
        [UIScreenmainScreen].applicationFrame];

        Compiling XXRootViewController.m (arm64)…
        XXRootViewController.m:9:1: error: expected ']'
        [UIScreenmainScreen].applicationFrame];
        ^
         1 error generated.
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I have tried many different methods to create this and I have imported all the files that I need for this to create successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is wondering, this is how I fixed the following error.

```
UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame]] autorelease];
```

Comment: `autorelease`? Please do yourself a giant favor and switch to ARC.

Comment: Im using theos (a command line tool for jailbroken devices that allows you to makes apps without xcode). Check it out at github.com/theos